# Trying to understand how sql query is generated by django framework?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I am using django debugger in pycharm to see how ORM does the magic. I have a simple model and a very basic query. Model.objects.get(id=1). The first step in click (debugger) takes me to django.db.models.manager.py. The **get** method of ManagerDescriptor class in this module is called. Then the pointer goes to django.db.models.query and as soon as the **init** method is complete the query is generated out of nowhere. Where did the query select Model.name, Model.age ... from Model come from?

On further digging I noticed that after the line self._defer_next_filter=False is executed the query property gets the value "select model.name, model.age ... from model".

```
class QuerySet:
    """Represent a lazy database lookup for a set of objects."""

    def __init__(self, model=None, query=None, using=None, hints=None):
        self.model = model
        self._db = using
        self._hints = hints or {}
        self._query = query or sql.Query(self.model)
        self._result_cache = None
        self._sticky_filter = False
        self._for_write = False
        self._prefetch_related_lookups = ()
        self._prefetch_done = False
        self._known_related_objects = {}  # {rel_field: {pk: rel_obj}}
        self._iterable_class = ModelIterable
        self._fields = None
        self._defer_next_filter = False  <<--- query generated after this line
        self._deferred_filter = None
```

I am sure I am missing something here, if anyone knows the internal working or can direct me to any tutorials on this please guide me. Thank you

```
Model.objects.get(id=1)
```

Comment: because Django Model class objects has built in pre defined query function, to see how your Django queryset convert to raw query you can add `.query` at the end of your queryset to see or for more detailed info use [.explain()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#explain)

Answer (score 0):

Django generates `SQL` query for ORM Querset not a single object
I mean you can print `SQL` query for `.filter()` or `.all()` not for `.get()`

NOTE - Here `.get()` method return a single object not return Queryset.

```
obj = Model.objects.filter(id=1)
print(obj.query)
```

Comment: I wanted to know which function generates the sql query? To be more specific the sql command 'SELECT * FROM MODEL WHERE ID=1'. Where is it generated in django??

Comment: you can inspect using Crtl + left-click on .query with  Vs code

Comment: the query is generated after the line Model.objects.get(id=1) is executed. There is a Queryset class in django.db.models.query. The init method creates the query. But I don't understand how.

Comment: print(obj .query.__dict__) try this